# Force.com IDE saving entire folder (instead of just the selected files)?

Tags: eclipse, force.com-ide

On v33.0. Every now and then, I need to select files individually from Eclipse's Package Explorer, and save them to server. Normally, Eclipse only saves the selected files, but I've had a few incidents recently where Eclipse decided to save the entire classes folder! This becomes problematic when team members share a sandbox.

Anyone else noticed this behaviour so far?

Comment: I know its silly but one of my team mate faced the same issue and struggled for almost 3 hrs, He has selected src folder first(By mistake) and then he was selecting multiple files by Ctrl+click. This maynot be the case with you but just check :)

Comment: @VikasKhandelwal Could be human error too. Would be nice if Eclipse had checkboxes for multi-selecting files, like in Mavensmate.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend moving to MavenMate, don't see nearly as many inconsistencies as Eclipse.

Comment: Tried mavensmate a while back. It's got useful features but I realized how attached I am to Eclipse: keyboard shortcuts and the EGit plugin, in particular. Planning to reevaluate MM again when I can afford the learning curve!

Comment: When you do get started these links should help: Setting up Git with MavensMate: https://tdd.instawiki.com/display/SF/Mavens+Mate+and+Git+for+Non+Developers and MavensMate shortcuts: http://mavensmate.com/Plugins/Sublime_Text/Shortcuts